# Azure mobile services facebook login without username/password

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have set up authentication with Azure Mobile Services using Facebook and Google successfully in my iOS app implemented in Xamarin.

It works fine but it does require the user to input username and password in some nasty web UI.

Ive seen may other apps and websites where you just click the facebook login and since you are already signed in with facebook on the device you just get some popup to accept and in you go without entering any username or password.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the Facebook SDK to achieve this. You can get it from the Xamarin component store [here (Facebook SDK Component)](http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios/)

I believe you are then able to pass the token to azure to log into the azure mobile services instance. [Something like this (This is for Windows Phone)](http://ntotten.com/2013/03/14/using-windows-azure-mobile-services-with-the-facebook-sdk-for-windows-phone/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go. I cant understand why microsoft made such a half measure with this.

Comment: I honestly dont think it is down to MS. Nobody is allowed to call into the FB app for authentication without using the FB SDK anyway. MS are just playing with the rules created by FB.

Comment: That worked. Thanks again. My app is now so much better. Do you know if you can do the same with google?

Comment: I am pretty sure you could using the G+ component http://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplusandplayios/

Comment: Ok, so now Im authenticating with Google plus successfully but when I then try to log in with the token to the mobile service like I did with facebook successfully I get: "Error: The Google API request failed with HTTP status code 400". Initially I got an error saying I needed to provide "code" and "id_token" as well which I then did and that error was replaced by the one above. Any ideas?

Comment: Now it seems like the latest versions of FB iOS SDK and Azure Mobile services are clashing. Is FB iOS SDK still the only way to get native FB logon instead of the web UI?